# Sorting array got error like cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sort')

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, pipe

I set up pipeline for sorting. It is sorting but I got this type of error:

> cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sort')

in angular core.js in my local running.

Here is my order-by.pipe.ts

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy',
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any, field: string): any[] {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

Comment: you could also do a console.log before array.sort to check what value is coming inside the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that `array` must have value then only proceed for sorting.

Meanwhile, you should specify `array` as `any[]` type as [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is a method provided by `Array`.

### Solution 1

Straight break the function when `array` is nullish (`null` or `undefined`).

```js
transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
  if (!array) return array;

  array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    if (a[field] < b[field]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });

  return array;
}
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvms2m?file=src/app/orderby-pipe.ts)

---

### Solution 2

Use [Typescript optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so that `.sort()` will not be executed when `array` is nullish (`null` or `undefined`).

```js
transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
  array?.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    if (a[field] < b[field]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
  
  return array;
}
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wcqwp3?file=src/app/orderby-pipe.ts)

Comment: I got type error TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]' for [items]="buildings$ | async | orderBy: 'buildingName'"

Comment: Hi, looks like the issue you faced is extension / not linked with this question. I would suggest you create a new question by providing a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Looking forward to your question.

Comment: Thanks Yong Shun. I just found the answer which is create copy of array before sorting it                                                                                                  
   transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
    if (!array) return array;
    array = [...array];
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });

    return array;
  }